# Type-error : network is undefined

Tags: javascript, firefox-os

I have the following code in a firefox app which I created (it gets network bandwidth and displays it in element with id="dynamicdata"):

```
//var battery = navigator.battery || navigator.mozBattery || navigator.webkitBattery;
var network = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection;

function getData()
{ // document.getElementById("dynamicdata").innerHTML = "The battery is at: " + battery.level*100 + "%";

     document.getElementById("dynamicdata").innerHTML = "The current bandwidth is: " + network.bandwidth + "MbPs";
 }
```

When I run my app  I get on console the following error: "TypeError: network is undefined".The same thing is working correctly for the commented battery status part.Where is it going wrong?

Comment: Means that none of the checks worked for the browser.

Comment: ^I am not sure what exactly you are asking..I am new to this stuff.

Comment: Means "navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection;" does  not support any of those it appears.

Comment: Ohk.. if that is the case, will I never get an output for "network.bandwidth"? Do I need to configure anything or download any APIs?

Comment: Which version of FirefoxOS do you have? On my FirefoxOS 1.3 mozConnection is present on the navigator object, it doesn't seem to require any permission. Yet the bandwidth I have on all of the apps I tested is always `Infinity`. So I'm not sure how we can limit the bandwidth of an app.

Comment: Firefox 38.0 Mozilla Firefox for ubuntu canonical - 1.0. The ubuntu version I have is 14.04.

Comment: So you're not using firefox os?

Comment: No I am not. The firefox has a simulator on which the apps I created run.But while running for this one, the console showed the error-"TypeError: network is undefined"

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/connection) `navigator.connection` is not supported on Desktop devices and is only supported on Mobile FF 12.0+ and Android 2.2+ (with webkit Prefix)

```
Feature         Chrome          Firefox (Gecko) Internet Explorer   Opera           Safari
Basic support   Not supported   Not supported   Not supported       Not supported   Not supported


Feature         Android     Firefox Mobile (Gecko) Firefox OS     IE Mobile       Opera Mobile   Safari Mobile
Basic support   2.2 webkit  12.0[1]                1.4            Not supporte    Not supported  Not supported
```

EDIT:

If you typo an object property, JS returns `undefined` because the property is.... undefined.

The error that you're getting, however, is `network` is undefined, not `network.bandwidth` is undefined, difference being that

- If `network` is undefined and you try to access `network.bandwidth`, that's an error
- If `network.bandwidth` is undefined and you try to access `network.bandwidth`, you just get `undefined` (no error).

Similarly, if `network` exists, but you try to reference `network.somerandompropertythatdoesntexist`, then you get `undefined` but no error.

Comment: oh. so it is not supported at all!

Comment: Unless you're developing for FF Mobile or Firefox OS, it appears not.

Comment: I dont know how relevant it is ,but i was following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e5WXsGkCBzE tutorial..But the person there gets "the network bandwidth is undefined" and someone pointed out in comments that he was using "network.bandwith" instead of "network.bandwidth"

Comment: Also note that, while the docs currently list support for `navigator.battery`, it's deprecated and will be removed ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/battery))

Comment: EDIT: I'm moving this comment to the answer since the formatting is terrible down here.

Comment: I am curious that if navigator.connection is not supported, do we have any other way of getting to know the bandwidth in a firefox OS app?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91884/discussion-between-arcyqwerty-and-shane).